# Exporting Google App Engine Datastore to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We're thinking of building some of our infrastructure on to Google App Engine. But we're worried that if it does not scale, we'll need to export the data and run it on our own servers in future.

Is there a way to export from App Engine Datastore to MySQL?

Comment: Your own infrastructure scales more than googles ? :s But anyway - theren's no prebuit way you'd have to write the data export yourself as part of the app.

Comment: GAE is not Google's infrastructure. It's only a subset they let you use. I wouldn't count on it being as reliable and resilient as Google's search service.

Comment: App Engine is _designed_ to scale, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as data export goes, the [Bulk Downloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Creating_Exporter_Classes) exists for just this purpose. By default it exports to CSV files, but you can write a custom Exporter class that exports directly to a MySQL database, or any other format of your choosing.

It's also rapidly becoming possible to host an alternate App Engine environment thanks to projects like [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/), (my own) [BDBDatastore](http://arachnid.github.com/BDBDatastore/), and [TwistedAE](http://code.google.com/p/twistedae/).

In general, I think your scaling concerns are unfounded - App Engine already hosts many apps that receive high levels of traffic, but that depends in part on your app and its needs. Of course, I'm biased - I'm on the App Engine team, so take my assessment with a grain of salt. ;)

Comment: I'd note that GAE scales, *if* you can write your program to use the datastore/BigTable "properly". But if you're doing work in Python to filter or compare result sets, that SQL is capable of doing in the database but BigTable is not, or if you use wide-ranging transactions, then your app quite possibly will scale better on a single-machine LAMP stack than it will on GAE.

Comment: Hence my comment "but that depends in part on your app and its needs". As far as filtering stuff in Python goes, although it's less efficient, it's only by a constant factor - doing it in the DB is still the same big-O runtime, so if it doesn't scale filtering in Python, it won't scale filtering linearly in the DB.