# Move data from datastore to MySQL(Cloud SQL)

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, migration, datastore

I am working on moving data from Google App engine datastore to Cloud SQL and I searched every where for any tool or process for this I Got few details/link are :
1. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring
3. https://johanndutoit.net/importing-a-datastore-backup-for-local-development-on-app-engine/
4. [Exporting Google App Engine Datastore to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317037/exporting-google-app-engine-datastore-to-mysql)

But didn't got the perfect solution. Can anyone please help me in findout the efficient approach, any tool or guidelines by which I can move complete data on Mysql.
Some table using other tables keys in their column values so we need to take care of key mismatch problem.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've asked Google Support this question myself recently (I am planning a similar migration), and their response was that there were no offical tools to support this.

Comment: Oh :( Google has provided both option Datastore and Cloud SQL. There should be something to do switching, NO?

Comment: I got an another related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811839/migrate-from-google-java-api-datastore-to-mysql But it show is for Python and my application developed in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed the migration from DataStore to CloudSQL. My Journey proceeded as follows:

1. Import Datastore data to google bigquery using cloud storage bucket.
2. Select data from bigquery as per desired db schema and export in Excel format.
3. Import the exported excel in Cloud SQL directly or converting into SQL script.

Above are the steps in summarized way which required to migrate from DataStore to CloudSql.